# Can't convert int pointer array to double pointer array in a function

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

I have a function that is supposed to convert an int pointer array to a double pointer array. It looks like this:

```
double* intToDouble(int len , int*x){

    double* y;
    y =(double*)malloc(len*sizeof(double));
    for (int i=0; i<len ; i++){
        y[i]=(double)x[i];
    }
    return y;
}
```

However, when trying to use it, I get an array full of float 0's . I will also leave here my print array function in case it is relevant.

```
void printDoubleSignal(int len, double* x) {
    printf("%d: [", len);
    if (len > 0) {
        printf("%lf", x[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) printf(",%lf", x[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

This is the result that I get after trying to convert from int to float the array 10: [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0]

```
10: [0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000]
```

**EDIT**
As requested, here is the rest of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

int* readSignal(int* len) {
    int* x;
    char c;
    scanf("%d:", len);
    x = calloc(*len, sizeof(int));
    do c = getchar(); while (c != '[');
    if (*len > 0) {
        scanf("%d", &x[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < *len; i++) scanf(",%d", &x[i]);
    }
    do c = getchar(); while (c != ']');
    return x;
}

void printSignal(int len, int* x) {
    printf("%d: [", len);
    if (len > 0) {
        printf("%d", x[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) printf(",%d", x[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

void printDoubleSignal(int len, double* x) {
    printf("%d: [", len);
    if (len > 0) {
        printf("%lf", x[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) printf(",%lf", x[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int* zeroPad(int len, int* x, int n){

    int i;
    x = (int*)realloc(x, sizeof(int) * n);
    for (i=len; i<n ; i++){
        x[i]=0;
    }
    return x;
}

double* intToDouble(int len , int* x){

    double *y;
    y =(double*)malloc(len*sizeof(double));
    for (int i=0; i<len ; i++){
        printf("x[%d]=%lf\n",i, x[i]);
        y[i]=x[i];
        printf("y[%d]=%lf\n",i, y[i]);
    }
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    int *x , len=5;
    double *y;
    x = readSignal(&len);
    printSignal(len,x);
    x = zeroPad(&len,x,10);
    printSignal(len,x);
    y = intToDouble(len,x);
    printDoubleSignal(len ,y);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
This is the exact text of the input/output (first line is input, the rest is output):

```
5:[1,2,3,4,5]
5: [1,2,3,4,5]
10: [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0]
x[0]=-0.000000
y[0]=-0.000000
x[1]=-0.000000
y[1]=-0.000000
x[2]=-0.000000
y[2]=-0.000000
x[3]=-0.000000
y[3]=-0.000000
x[4]=-0.000000
y[4]=-0.000000
x[5]=-0.000000
y[5]=-0.000000
x[6]=-0.000000
y[6]=-0.000000
x[7]=-0.000000
y[7]=-0.000000
x[8]=-0.000000
y[8]=-0.000000
x[9]=-0.000000
y[9]=-0.000000
10: [0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000]
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2aDelzfzu3oPy0y2). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the caller of these functions.

Comment: The issue is in the code you are not showing.

Comment: @MikeCAT  I have just updated it with an edit of my whole (short) code.

Comment: Tip: When debugging floating point issues, it is more informative to printf with `"%e"` or `"%g"` than `"%f"` .

Comment: Udar, Post the input used  (exact text) and output seen.  Was it `"10: [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0]\n"` or something like that?  Output from `printSignal()` missing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have just edited the post with the input/output

Comment: Some older compilers do not work well with printing and  `l` in `%lf`.  Try `"%g"`. (no ell)

Comment: `printf("x[%d]=%lf\n",i, x[i]);` is garbage with `int *x`.  Enable all warnings and save time.

Comment: Code lacks `#include <stdio.h>` - that explains a lot.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I just forgot to add it in the post, edited it. Also I ve tried with %g  and %e and besides the fact that x[0] looks like x[0]=1.78917e-307 , I also need the result with only 5 decimal points.

Comment: I just changed %lf to %f and it works fine. No idea why. Thank you all!

Comment: @Udar You are using an old C compiler that does not understand `"l"`.  Look to using a newer compiler, C99 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to receive the result of `zeroPad`. The function uses `realloc()`, so the passed pointer may be invalidated. The function returns the new pointer, so you have to assign that to `x`.

This means that the line in the `main()` function

```
    zeroPad(5,x,10);
```

should be

```
    x = zeroPad(5,x,10);
```

Comment: I seem to have fixed that, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Looks like x is not passed correctly to the intToDouble function. I have tried to print it inside the for loop of the function, and x[i] is also 0.00000 . Any idea why?

Comment: See comment above  "I just changed %lf to %f and it works fine. No idea why".  Looks like OP is using a pre-c99 compiler.  Might want to add that to this good answer.